# Slim3 Upload target path is not writable

Tags: slim, mount

An error occurred while uploading a file to the external storage mounted by Slim 3.
(CentOS7, Apache2.4, PHP7, Slim3)

[mount command]

```
mount -t cifs -o username=username,password=password //External-Storage-IP /data/static
```

[file upload code]

```
$directory = '/data/static';
$uploadedFile->moveTo($directory . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $filename);
```

[error]

```
file: ~/vendor/slim/slim/Slim/Http/UploadedFile.php
message: Upload target path is not writable.
```

Looking inside the vendor's UploadedFile file code, 'is_writable' returns false.

I think it's a problem with the permissions of the mount disk, so I'm looking into it...

Is there something I'm doing wrong?
Please Help. Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

---

I've been searching, and it seems that I need to use symlinks to solve this problem.
The upload directory in the web project was created as a symbolic link. But I get the same error.

pwd: webdata/uploads

```
ln -s /data/static static
```

Comment: As you guessed, the user from the web server has no write permissions to the directory

Comment: @tino.codes I've been searching, and it seems that I need to use symlinks to solve this problem. The upload directory in the web project was created as a symbolic link. But I get the same error.